# Updating website as soon as intermediate plots are ready

Tags: ajax, flask, streaming

Dependent on a selection, made on a website, plots are generated on a server where Flask runs.

The issue that I have is that generating e.g. 10 different plots can take up to 30s. What I like to achieve is to start updating the website as soon as the first plot is ready and then load automatically the others as soon as they are ready.

Currently, the following AJAX function is executed as soon as the user hits the "process" button on the website:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/single",
        data: { athleteName1: $('#athleteName1').val(), style: $('#style').val()},
        success: function (results) {
            $('#results').empty().append(results);
            $('#results').show();
            $('#submitbutton').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

On the server site, plots are created and embedded in div-containers. They are subsequently concatenated an returned to the website at once as "diagStr":

```
@app.route('/single', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def single():
    loop 10 times:
        diagStr += generate_plot()
    return Markup(diagStr)
```

Doing it with "Streaming Contents" can only be part of the solution as AJAX waits until the the entire response is received.

Any idea how this is solved with today's technology?

Comment: I will send multiple requests in parallel:
Each request will generate only one plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way you could achieve this, but some simple examples:

- do your looping on the client side, and generate 10 separate Ajax requests, updating the web page when each response is received.
- if you don't know in advance on the client side, how many loops you will have, then use a single request and have the server send the response as soon as the first loop is complete, along with a flag indicating whether there are more loops or not - the client can look at this flag and create a new Ajax request if there are more loops.

Comment: The first solution is perfect as multiple requests can be sent in parallel.

Comment: However, in case of AJAX "error:", I'm having troubles to identify the responsible request for proper error handling.

Comment: The AJAX responses will each be steered to their own callback, unless you set it up differently - take a look at this for example of different ways to handle multiple calls (link good at time of writing, but basically shows single calls, sequential calls with next call in preceding calls callback processing, and parallel using deferred): https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Comment: Raised a question for it on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851575/identifying-ajax-request)....