# Identifying AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am triggering multiple AJAX requests in a loop. They run in parallel and it is not clear which one will respond first.
If the response is successful, I can identify the request by analyzing the response.

```
for (kk = 0; kk < $('#style').val().length; kk++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/single",
        data: {style: [$('#style').val()[kk]]},
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.status == 'success'){
                $('#results').find('div').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('id') == results.style){
                        $(this).empty().append(results.payload)
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#results').find('div').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('id') == results.style){
                        $(this).empty().append('<b>' + results.style + ':</b> ' + results.payload)
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {

            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

However, once in a while, the request fails and an error is triggered.
For a proper error handling, I would like to know to which of the (previously triggered) requests the error belongs.

Is there a clean method how a specific AJAX request can be identified?

Comment: you can pass loop iteration kk  into the ajax call and get it back in response from server side

Comment: I would not recommend using AJAX calls with `async:false` in a loop as this will continuously cause blocks. Rather I would recommend to use the AJAX `context` to identify the call later-on.

Comment: Yep, using `async:false` is not an option as one request takes about 2-3s in my application.

Comment: @Ajay2707 That's a really bad advice. you should only use `async :false` if the request has to block the code execution (and that case is really rare, in almost every case you want it to be async) and should never be used as a workaround to solve a problem that could be solved another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to pass in a identifier via `context` to the AJAX call which you can use inside the `success` or `error` methods:

```js
for (kk = 0; kk < $('#style').val().length; kk++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/single",
        data: {style: [$('#style').val()[kk]]},
        // data inside "context" will be available as part of "this" in the success/error case. 
        context: {
          "kk": kk
        },
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.status == 'success'){
                console.log("Element " + this.kk + " finished successfully.");
                $('#results').find('div').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('id') == results.style){
                        $(this).empty().append(results.payload)
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                $('#results').find('div').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('id') == results.style){
                        $(this).empty().append('<b>' + results.style + ':</b> ' + results.payload)
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Element " + this.kk + "failed.");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

More information regarding `context` can be found in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Regarding your comment about checking how many calls failed / succeeded: here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/km2jacfz/) demonstrating how to keep track of the call statistics.

Comment: That was what I was looking for!
Any idea how to know if particular response is the last one of the parallelly triggered requests?

Comment: Create a variable outside the loop containing the number of AJAX calls in total. Decrease the number by 1 inside the `success`/`error` call. When an error occurs you, you can check how many calls are left.

Comment: I am not a java specialist but I am wondering if this could potentially creates runtime errors as multiple request may access the variable at the same time?

Comment: Don't confuse Java and Javascript. Javascript is single-threaded and is only able to "emulate" multithreading by pushing actions to external APIs via the "event loop". Whenever one of these external processes finishes, it will be pushed to the stack when there is no currently running function, otherwise it will be queued. Just learned that through this [brilliant JS talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: @MikePenrose just added a demo to my answer to show that there are no concurrency problems with variable access in JS.

Comment: This is a neat example! I wasn't aware of the feature `url: "/echo/json` in jsfiddle.

Comment: @MikePenrose I know, that's really great to emulate complex applications. Also available for XML and HTML, see [here](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests)

Comment: Parallel requests are now up and running @ [swimstats](http://www.swimstats.net). However, it's another story if the server can cope with the traffic.

Comment: @MikePenrose Neat! Seems to be working fine, also very interesting web page! If my answer helped you solve your problem, I would appreciate if you would mark it as an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, although I am very pleased with the proposed solution I can't "mark it as answer" as my reputation is too low.

Comment: @MikePenrose as the question author you should always be able to mark an answer. Just have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)